Ignore Comma Delimiter in CsvHelper
I've a project that uses CsvHelper package to parse excel file. Unfortunately I came into a condition where I've to ignore comma as delimiter that CsvHelper does by default I believe. The data in a single column looks as follows in the excel file:
Company_Name
ABC Group, NY

When it gets parsed and try to bind it in a variable, I get something as follows:
ABC Group
NY

The first variable has the value ABC Group and second variable is set to NY. Though the first variable should have ABC Group, NY. In backend, I've something as follows and tried to set the delimiter value:
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    Delimiter = "/", //Tried to ignore comma as delimiter
    PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.ToLower(),
    ShouldSkipRecord = (args) =>
    {
        var companyCode = args.Record[1];
        var companyName = args.Record[2]; //Here I get the value and the delimiter actually splits data in this line of code
        var companyAccountNumber = args.Record[3];
        var pccid = args.Record[16];


        var isHeader = pccid?.ToLower().Contains("client_number") ?? false;

        var shouldSkip =
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pccid) ||
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(companyName) ||
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(companyCode) ||
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(companyAccountNumber)
            && !isHeader;

        if (shouldSkip)
            skipped.Add(args.Record);

        return shouldSkip;
    }
};

Unfortunately it says Index out of array bounds when I use the delimiter to set. Is there any way to handle this in CsvHelper (Version 27.1.1) or ignore comma as delimiter?
N.B: When the comma is removed, it works as expected. I mean the data gets wrapped in a single variable.

Please clarify what you mean by "Excel file" - because that normally refers to *.xlsx files, which are not CSV files. If you mean an "Excel (dialect) CSV" file that's exported from Excel without quoted strings then you're SOL because it really is quite literally impossible to differentiate between a comma-in-a-string vs. a comma field separator. If you didn't create this (invalid) file then you'll need to contact whoever did create it and tell them to ensure the file conforms to RFC 4180.

It's a .xlsx file @Dai.

CsvHelper cannot read .xlsx files. I suspect you have an invalid .csv file that's simply been renamed to .xlsx.

You have to use value delimiters so it won't split on every comma. In default csv files, this is double quotes. But then you have to escape double quotes in your values! If you decide you want to change the delimiter, you can create a CsvHelper.Configuration.Configuration instance with your new settings and pass that to the CsvReader's constructor.

Is it possible to share a code snippet like how I can do that? @ps2goat.

@user8512043 Click the Edit link on your posting and add it to your existing post - you might want to add a horizontal-line separator by using dashes.

Assuming that the file is a csv file
You can try different things:

If your CSV data can be modified, the best practice is to enclose fields containing commas with quotes. For example: "ABC Group, NY"
If changing the delimiter is an option, ensure that the chosen delimiter does not appear in your data. For example, you could use a pipe (|) or a tab (\t)
If you cannot modify the CSV data or change the delimiter, you might need to handle the commas manually. This involves merging the fields that were split incorrectly. it'll give something like that:

var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    Delimiter = ",",
    PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.ToLower(),
    ShouldSkipRecord = (args) =>
    {
        var record = args.Record;
        var companyName = string.Join(",", record.Skip(1).Take(2)); // Merge the fields manually
        var companyCode = record[1];
        var companyAccountNumber = record[3];
        var pccid = record[16];

        var isHeader = pccid?.ToLower().Contains("client_number") ?? false;

        var shouldSkip =
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pccid) ||
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(companyName) ||
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(companyCode) ||
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(companyAccountNumber)
            && !isHeader;

        if (shouldSkip)
            skipped.Add(args.Record);

        return shouldSkip;
    }
}; 


Didn't work @Rad Taren.

I can understand what didn't work could you clarify, and it works only with csv files not xlsx
